# java multiple thread isalive or not

Tags: java, multithreading

this way i am generating threads,but after for loop how to check that all threads are alive or not
further process depends on the all threads 
if threads are `dead` then go for further process

```
for (int i = 0;i<List.size();i++) {
                if(List.get(i).trim().length() >0 ){

                    Thread thread = new Thread("Thread"+i){
                        public void run(){              
                            threading(List.get(i),ctx,userSesionObj);
                        }
                      };
                      thread.start();
                }
            }
```

here `threading` is my function which perform on different data that i pass

Comment: You can store them in a `List<Thread>` and wait for them. Or you can use an ExecutorService and wait for it as a thread group.

Comment: by "wait", @Peter means calling `join()`.

Comment: You can `join()` the thread or `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` for the ExecutionService.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't call `wait()` ...

Comment: i try it. but with that my process not work further process, it stuck there. It may my problem or not useful in this case. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). I'd strongly recommend this, in fact. You can specify different threading behaviour etc. The executor will return a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object for each submitted thread, and then you can iterate through each `Future` collecting the results. So the following:

```
for (Future f : futures) {
   f.get(); // get a result here...
}
```

will complete when all the `Futures` have returned data (i.e. when the threads have completed). The Executor API works at a higher level than `join()`/`notify()` etc. and is a lot safer to use.

There's a lot of features to make use of here and I would recommend the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to `join` the threads. Cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html.  Given that you can suspend your main thread, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ExecutorService`

**-** `Executors` Manages the `Thread` objects and `Async` Task well

**-** Here it Not the client that run the thread directly, but and intermediate object.

**-** Combining this with `submit()` method which returns a `Future` Object.

**-** `Future` is the **resultant** of the async task.

**-** You can use the `get()` method of Future, which is of **blocking nature**, or `get()` method along with `isDone()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method *isAlive* from the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) class.

From the documentation:

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Comment: and if they are still alive do what?

Comment: @Thilo what do you mean? The author wants to check if thread are alive or not, this is what this method does.

Comment: He also wants to wait until they are no longer alive. And that is the interesting part here.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter suggested, this should do...

```
int count = selectedCategoryList.size();
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  if(selectedCategoryList.get(i).trim().length() >0 ){
    final Long CategoryID = Long.parseLong(selectedCategoryList.get(i));
    Thread thread = new Thread("ReplaceMedicationThread"+i){
                          public void run(){              
                            threadingForReplacingMedication(CategoryID,ctx,userSesionObj);
                          }
                    };
    threads.add(thread):
   }
}

//start them in a loop
//join them in a loop
//move on....
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to wait for some threads to finish before continuing processing is by means of  a CompletionService. This is how you would use this:

```
// list of data that need to be processed before continuing execution
List<DataForProcessing> workList = // ...

// An instance of an Executor http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html
Executor exec = // ...

// asume that ResultData is a data structure returned from the processing each
// DataForProcessing instance. If processing does not return a value you could
// parameterise the completion service as CompletionService<Void>.
CompletionService<ResultData> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<ResultData>(executor);

// Submit the tasks for processing. Each task will be processed by the executor and
// its result will be wrapped in a Future and place in a BlockingQueue maintained by
// the CompletionService instance. Again, if your submitted task does not return
// a value you should parameterise your task as Callable<Void>.
for (DataForProcessing data: workList) {
  service.submit(new Callable<ResultData>() {
    public ResultData call() {
      // process the data here and return some result (optionally).
    }
  });
 }

// retrieve the results as the become available.
for (int i = 0; i < workLoad.size(); i++) {
  // Retrieve the next processed result. CompletionService returns each task in a
  // Future which provides you with the means to control the lifecycle of the task.
  // When a submitted task is processed by the executor, its Future is placed on a
  // BlockingQueue maintained by the CompletionService. Invoking take() will return
  // the next available result. If your tasks do not return a result you would still
  // need to call Future<Void> f = service.take() in order to wait for every task
  // to finish before proceeding.
  Future<ResultData> f = service.take();
  // If your task returns some result you may access it via the get() method on the
  // task's Future.
  ResultData result = f.get();
  // do some processing if needed
  process(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just done it with simple one global int parameter.
I do just like this:

```
do{
    Thread.sleep(800);
    System.out.println("threadCounter=="+threadCounter);
    }while(threadCounter != 0);
```

where `threadCounter` define globally `int` initialize `zero`

on making of every thread i do +1 of `threadCounter`;

and in my function `threading` at the and i do -1 of `threadCounter`

here `Thread.sleep(800)` for not run that do-while loop continues.

Comment: here i get my proper answer not to do any big thing in program.thanks to all for give such good response.